# Count number of different ip's in a query in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a little help here with a query. I want to count from a result set duplicate ip's and put that together with a username.

the origional result set is

```
Name | IP
--------------
Bert | 192.168.1.1
Bert | 192.168.1.5
Laura| 192.168.1.2
```

and I want this:

```
Name | IpCount
--------------
Bert | 2
Laura| 1
```

My query so far is:

```
select ips.userName, COUNT(ips.userIP) as cnt 
from (select u.userName, u.userIP from 
users) as ips
group by ips.userName, ips.userIP
```

But that gives me the wrong counts, can somebody help me?

EDIT:

I used the word duplicate, but it should be: different. Sorry folks.

Comment: You don't have duplicate IP addresses in your example, so I'm a bit confused as to what exactly you're after.

Comment: I want to count per user with how many different ip's they've been logging in.

Comment: In my opinion, your "original" result-set is misleading. You should add a new row for the user Bert (for ex.) with a duplicate IP: `Bert,192.168.1.1`, `Bert, 192.168.1.1` and `Bert, 192.168.1.5`. So, will be clear that you want to to count DISTINCT ip's for every name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your example has a typo and you mean

```
Name | IP
--------------
Bert | 192.168.1.1
Bert | 192.168.1.1
Laura| 192.168.1.2
```

and your table is named Users. This query should do

```
select Name, COUNT(IP) as cnt 
from users
group by Name
```

**Update**

as pointed out by @Andriy M this query should do

```
select Name, COUNT(distinct IP)
from users
group by Name
```

Comment: I want to count per user with how many different ip's they've been logging in.

Comment: @Elger: Change to `COUNT(DISTINCT IP)` then.

Comment: @Iridio: No, you just need to add the `DISTINCT` keyword, like in my comment.

Comment: @AndriyM: you are perfectly right. Corrected the answer. Thanks for pointing that out. I never stop to learn :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   name, COUNT(*) as Totalcount
FROM     users
GROUP BY name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Or only users with more than 1 ip:

```
SELECT   name, COUNT(*)
FROM     users
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```